# Scrape data from public facebook page only to see if there's been updates from group itself

Tags: php, web-scraping, web-applications

So I've searched the web end on end looking for just the steps to get me in the right direction but can't seem to find it.

So what i'm trying to do is as follow:

Create a web application with [php](/questions/tagged/php) that has simple functionality.

Functionality as follows:

Firstly - It needs to go check a public facebook group to see if the group itself has made a post, and if so the app needs to return a circle. The circle will be an indication that there's been a public post.

Secondly - If there's been no public post it needs to display a different color circle.

Thirdly - if there were no schedule posts for that day it needs to display another different color circle.

I'm trying to do this WITHOUT facebook graph API and without access tokens. As far as i understand there's no need for tokens as its a public group making public posts.

I've also read up a but about [php-curl](/questions/tagged/php-curl)  but so far I can't manage to get what i'm looking for.

All i ask for is guidance in the right direction or what you can offer me.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the API is the suggested method but if you really want to scrape post info you can try https://pastebin.com/QjxN0ZUY

This part in the code is where you define the regex of what you want to extract, in this demo I have just extracted the date of the post as it was the easiest.

```
$searchREGEX = '/\<abbr\>(.|\n)*?\<\/abbr\>/';
```

Hope this helps, good luck !

Comment: Thanks a million for the help. Definitely helped solve my problem I had.

Comment: I apologize for my ignorance. Is it there a way to get any information without a regular expression? Or how can I get the rest of the information, not only the post's date? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nevermind, I found a way by learning REGEXP on https://regexr.com/, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you can try what @zac is suggesting you can also try and use 1 or more scraping methods.

for me i scrape sometimes with PHP-curl and the Dom Document to read what i get. this can be heavy because you need to pull the web page every x amount of time.

Next what i use also for testing but is suitable for web scraping or just going on other sites is Panther (https://github.com/symfony/panther) this uses a web browser so you can also incorporate some sort of screenshot system to see if you have the right data ()